# Pattern Matching Pass Through in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to do something like this:

```
val a = v match {
   case 1 => 1
   case 2 if (condition) => logging
   case 2 if (other conditions) => 3
   case 2 if (more conditions) => 4
   case _ => 5
}
```

I want this to return just log for first case 2, but fall through otherwise to see what gets returned

edit:  updated

Comment: Why don't you write real code that runs and does what you want, with if statements and returns and whatever you need, and then ask how to improve it?  I'm not sure what you actually want here.

Comment: That is not yet real code that runs and does what you want.  You're still imagining that match statements work a different way than they actually do, and then hoping we can guess what you are imagining.

Comment: What they are requesting is similar to the OR'd match patterns in F#, where multiple patterns can result in the the same case's output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala's case matching doesn't "fall through", but if I understand correctly, this will do what you want.

```
val a = v match {
  case 1 => 1
  case 2 => {
    logging // I'm assuming `logging` is some Unit
    if(some condition) 3
    else if(some other condition) 4
    else 5
  }
  case _ => 5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

If `v == 2`, `a` will be assigned `logging` otherwise `a` will be assigned the value of `v`

```
val a = v match {
   case 2 => logging
   case _ => v
}
```

Comment: my logic is more like if v = 2, log, and then fall through, so in this case, it'll go to the default case _ and return 4.